# Appending a row to last in the output of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table **magazine(name, category, weight)**. I have to print out rows 
with **category, total weight in this category**
. Till this it's just group by clause
But the last row of the result should have **('total',total-weight)** ie. the last row of the query
should contain this special entry with tuple containing the total weight of all magazines
If I just use simple union that won't work as there is no guarantee that it will be appear as 
the last item in the query

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(category, 'Total') as category, sum(weight)
from magazine m
group by grouping sets ( (category), () )
order by m.category nulls last;
```

Comment: I am running this on postgresql. I am getting a syntax error in this ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 4: group by grouping sets ( (cat), () );
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 79   The actual column name in my table is `cat`

Comment: @dreamcrash . . . I don't think the OP has enough reputation yet to upvote answers.  Of course, other people can ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is more than 15 points :P. Btw I wanted to tell you that you are simply a machine ahah

Comment: @dreamcrash . . . Gosh.  I thought it was 50 points, but that is something I don't often think about.

Comment: ok. Yeah the query works now.  But Total comes at the top. I want it to bring to bottom. Thanks a lot for your help